# Create hive table using "as select" or "like" and also specify delimiter

Tags: hive, sql-like, create-table

Is it possible to do a

`create table <mytable> as select <query statement>`

using

```
row format delimited fields terminated by '|';
```

or to do a

`create table <mytable> like <other_table> row format delimited fields terminated by '|';`

The Language Manual seems to indicate not.. but something tickles me I had achieved this in the past.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

> **Create Table as select (CTAS) is possible in Hive.**

You can try out below command:

```
CREATE TABLE new_test 
    row format delimited 
    fields terminated by '|' 
    STORED AS RCFile 
AS select * from source where col=1
```

1. Target cannot be partitioned table.
2. Target cannot be external table.
3. It copies the structure as well as the data

> **Create table like is also possible in Hive.**

1. It just copies the source table definition.

Comment: Very well done answer!  Addresses both (a) the specific syntax and (b) the limitations. Just what I was looking for.

Comment: @Venkatesh, What will be the default field terminator/separator if i didn't mention it in case of `CREATE TABLE <table_name> AS SELECT <some query from target table>`. Will it use the target table's field separator or some default field separator.?

Comment: @Manindar default hive delimiter is `^A` or `(ctrl-a)`

Answer (score 6):

Let's say we have an external table called `employee`

```
hive> SHOW CREATE TABLE employee;
OK
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE employee(
  id string,
  fname string,
  lname string, 
  salary double)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'colelction.delim'=':',
  'field.delim'=',',
  'line.delim'='\n',
  'serialization.format'=',')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'maprfs:/user/hadoop/data/employee'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='false',
  'numFiles'='0',
  'numRows'='-1',
  'rawDataSize'='-1',
  'totalSize'='0',
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1487884795')
```

1. To create a `person` table like `employee`

   `CREATE TABLE person LIKE employee;`
2. To create a `person` external table like `employee`

   `CREATE TABLE person LIKE employee LOCATION 'maprfs:/user/hadoop/data/person';`
3. then use 
   `DESC person;` 
   to see the newly created table schema.

Comment: I tried this but TBLPROPERTIES are not getting copied. Anyway to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Both the answers provided above work fine.

1. CREATE TABLE person AS select * from employee;
2. CREATE TABLE person LIKE employee;