# Create hive external table with partitions

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have already an internal table in hive. Now I want to create an external table with partitions based on date to it. But it throws error, when I try to create it.

Sample code:

```
create external table db_1.T_DATA1 partitioned by (date string) as select * from db_2.temp
LOCATION 'file path';
```

Error:

> ParseException line 2:0 cannot recognize input near 'LOCATION' ''file
>   path'' '' in table source

Comment: I don't believe you can create an external table using create table as select. Just create the table normally, and insert your data.

Comment: Ok.
Thanks for the response.  I have created the table manually.

Answer (score 1):

As per the answer provided at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26722320/4326922 you should be able to create external table with CTAS.