# Hash columns while copying table

Tags: sqoop

I need to **hash** certain columns (like *email*) while copying `MySQL` tables to `HDFS` using [`Sqoop`](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html).

- Is there a built-in option in `sqoop`?
- If not, how can this be achieved?

---

**EDIT-1**

Currently I could think of a very *crude* way to achieve this: [passing a `SQL` query](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_free_form_query_imports) (instead of table-name) like following to `sqoop`

```
SELECT
  `name`,
  SHA1(`email`) AS `email`,
  `dob`
FROM
  `my_db`.`users`
```

- Not sure if this would work at all [will update once I've tried]
- Even if it works, it (most probably) would require generating `SQL`-query specific to underlying DB (`MySQL`, `PostgreSQL` etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a built-in option in `sqoop`?

No

---

> If not, how can this be achieved?

- **Approach-1**: use `SQL`-*query* as already described in question
- **Approach-2**: another straight-forward way would be to perform a 2-step import

  - do a `sqoop import` into a `Hive` *temp*-table
  - create a new `Hive` table from this *temp* table and perform `hash`ing in the process (a good approach would be [`Hive` `CTAS`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22249739/create-hive-table-using-as-select-or-like-and-also-specify-delimiter))