# Create Hive table using “as select” and also specify TBLPROPERTIES

Tags: hive

For example, when using Parquet format, I'd like to be able to specify the compression scheme (`("parquet.compression"="SNAPPY")`). Running this query:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a_copy
STORED AS PARQUET
TBLPROPERTIES("parquet.compression"="SNAPPY")
AS
SELECT * FROM table_a
```

returns an error:

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:69 cannot recognize input near 'parquet' '.' 'compression' in table properties list (state=42000,code=40000)
```

The same query without the `TBLPROPERTIES` works just fine.

This is similar to this question: [Create hive table using "as select" or "like" and also specify delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22249739/create-hive-table-using-as-select-or-like-and-also-specify-delimiter). But I can't figure out how to make `TBLPROPERTIES` work with that approach. I'm using Hive 1.1.

Comment: Hi, what type of table is table_a? It's parquet?

Comment: @F.Lazarescu: for the purposes of this question, I'd rather get a solution that works independent of the source table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to run same exact statement in **`Hive 2.1.1`** version.

**`Try with this workaround:`**

```
CREATE TABLE table_a_copy like table_a STORED AS PARQUET;
alter table set TBLPROPERTIES("parquet.compression"="SNAPPY");
insert into table table_a_copy select * from table_a ;
```

Comment: Indeed I have an older version of Hive, v1.1. The workaround works though!