# How to create a bucketed ORC transactional table in Hive that is modeled after a non-transactional table

Tags: hive, hiveql, orc

Suppose I have a non-transactional table in Hive named 'ccm'.  It has hundreds of columns and one partition field.

I know how to create a copy with "create table abc like ccm'  but I would like abc to be bucketed, ORC, and have transaction support set on via TBLPROPERTIES.

I do not want to mention all the columns in ccm  when I compose the HQL.

Can I do this?

Answer (score -1):

This answer may have the correct way to proceed in your case, and it also explains some limitation of the method used.

[Create hive table using "as select" or "like" and also specify delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22249739/create-hive-table-using-as-select-or-like-and-also-specify-delimiter)

So, from the example, you should add the missing parts:

- CLUSTER BY
- TBLPROPERTIES ("transactional"="true")

I have some doubts that you can achieve exactly your expected results but i would consider it as a step forward

Comment: The target table is partitioned;  the message I get when I run this:

`hive> create table test clustered by (acctnum) into 50 buckets stored as ORC tblproperties('transactional'='true') as select * from ccm;` 

 is:  

`FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10068]: CREATE-TABLE-AS-SELECT does not support partitioning in the target table`

Comment: That was my impression as well, i think that the cluster by here is unusable. If i find another way I'll post it here. At the moment, i don't have any remarkable method

Comment: Have you tried create with CTAS and once created alter the table with ALTER ddl?

Comment: My intention is to create a table "like" a large table example, but to make this table transactional.  I am failing because the large example table is partitioned.